# Finding and replacing words in a textarea in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function clean(e){
    var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
    var regex = /[^a-z 1-9 ,.!?-`'"()\r\n   ]/gi;
    var wrongWords = new Array("can't", "I", "won't");
    var rightWords =  new Array("can not", "people", "will not");
    var x = 0
    if(textfield.value.search(regex) > -1) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "We found invalid characters";
        textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "");
    }
    while(textfield.value.search(wrongWords) === true){
        textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(wrongWords[x], rightWords[x]);
        x++;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the while statement. An how can I get it to work?

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The answer to those question depends on what the code is *supposed* to do (which you did not describe). For next time, please include a brief description of what the code IS doing and how it differs from what you expected (actual versus expected results). Help others to help you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

> ```
> var wrongWords = new Array("can't", "I", "won't");
> ...
> ... textfield.value.search(wrongWords) ...
> ```

you are calling `search` which expects a regular expression, but is getting an array of words so it ends up searching for a regular expression like `/can't,I,won't/` since coercing an array to a `RegExp` invokes the arrays `toString` method which joins on `","`.

You can verify that

```
RegExp(["foo", "bar"]).source === "foo,bar"
```

Maybe

```
textfield.value.search(wrongWords[x])
```

would get closer to what you want but it doesn't match whole words.  It will find the 'I's in "In the year MMXIII, ..."

To solve that, you could try boundary checks:

```
textfield.value.search("\\b" + wrongWords[x] + "\\b")
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether search returns -1 but not true.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Comment: This should be a comment... And w3fools reference may bring you a downvote... :)

Comment: @PSL gah you have a infinite recursive call on your profile page.... sad day. :-)

Comment: :) Yeah... Regd w3schools link i remember getting down-voted twice just for posting it some months back.. :(